# Where is the drop down option for webtemplate 1 SharePoint Design Templates in "Create a SharePoint Site"?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-template

I added a SharePoint Design using webtemplate 1, but can't find anywhere in "Create a SharePoint Site" to select it. It's not in Other Options which is where I'd assumed it would be, nor in the normal TeamSite or Communcation Site drop downs.

Templates based on 64 and 68 show fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, we could create site designs and register them in SharePoint to one of the modern template sites: a group-connected Team site(WebTemplate ID is 64) or the Communication site(WebTemplate ID is 68).

If you have disabled modern Group creation, you could publish your site designs using WebTemplate 1 so that they display for the "Group-less" Team site template.

So the newly registered site design will not be displayed under inconsistent web template when you create a new site, however you can apply the site design to current site via site settings> Site Designs which will show as expected.

Comment: Thanks Julie. I need it to be selectable from the creation page and was hoping to avoid Office 365 groups. All good. I'll just use Office 365 groups for it. Thanks for you answer!